# Are application specific scripting languages on topic for this site?

Tags: discussion

I am an auditor and I would love some feedback on a script I wrote some time back using the Audit Command Language - ACL.

Is such application specific languages on topic here?

Comment: [Here seems to be the language's homepage](http://www.acl.com/).

Comment: Related? http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6608/lisp-like-dsl-code-review.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience ACL does have back-end scripting capabilities and the language is significantly different than (for instance) VBA. And VBA is application specific too.

I would say it's **on-topic**, but it might not have too many reviewers as I don't know how many users would have access to it or experience with it. That being said, it's simple enough to review the logic and find documentation, so I don't think that it would go unanswered.

I gave it a shot at my last auditing job and it was too unlike VBA for me, so I stuck to VBA considering excel handles over 1 million records, albeit not as well as ACL. There's also an (free) [excel ACL Add-in](http://www.acl.com/products/acl-excel-add-in/) that I've messed around with and it deals with excel functions which have been deemed [on-topic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2118/can-we-review-spreadsheet-formulas) previously.

And as linked by Martin R in the comments, [Lisp-like DSL code review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6608/lisp-like-dsl-code-review) is domain specific and on-topic.

That being said, there may be some confusion with ACL also being a (more relevant here) acronym for Access Control Lists.