# CODE REVIEW 2017 Challenge

Tags: discussion, fun, community-challenge, bounty

I want to introduce the **C**ommunity **O**riented **D**evelopment **E**xtravaganza, **R**equiring **E**xtreme **V**igor **I**nciting **E**xtraordinary **W**inners (or **CODE REVIEW**) 2017 Challenge. Traditionally our Community Challenges are non-competitive, this challenge aims to change that *just a bit*.

We usually have these challenges run for a month, and we announce them a month in advance except in certain situations where we want to boost participation. This time I'm going to run the announcement for three (3) months and run the challenge another three (3) months. At the end of the 6-month period, I will award a **500 reputation bounty** to the winner of the challenge.

Major dates for the challenge are below:

- **Thursday, 1 June 2017**: Challenge begins accepting suggestions
- **Thursday, 31 August 2017 23:59:59 UTC+0000**: Challenge finishes accepting suggestions
- **Friday, 1 September 2017 00:00:00 UTC+0000**: Challenge begins
- **Thursday, 30 November 2017 23:59:59 UTC+0000**: Challenge ends
- **Friday, 1 December 2017**: Winner is announced from entries

## How does one win?

In order to support the idea of a winner, we have to make sure that there is something to 'win'. Each challenge suggestion must have a detailed list of possible points to be awarded, and the participants are graded based on how many total points they earned (out of possible points).

The exact details of the awards will be announced later in the season, but at a minimum the following will be awarded:

- The first-place winner will receive a 500-reputation bounty;
- In the case of multiple first-place winners then each winner will receive a 250-reputation bounty;

If participation is high (left to the discretion of the members of the community who are offering the rewards) then an additional tiered reward system may be put in place.

## How should suggestions differ from normal?

The only difference that suggestions require from traditional [community-challenge](/questions/tagged/community-challenge) questions is that they **must** detail specific features that require implementation and the total point-count for each feature. Challenge suggestions may mark features as 'optional' or 'required', and if a participant fails to implement all 'required' features then they are disqualified.

You may **not** reuse any previous community challenge selections as normally required, but you *may* re-suggestion un-selected challenges, and suggest challenges that are somewhat large in scope.

## How does one enter as a participant?

A [question with the entry requirements](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8442/code-review-2017-challenge-entries) (also included below) and a list of all entries will be posted on **Friday, 1 September 2017**.

Participating is easy, and simply requires one to meet all criteria below:

- Complete all required portions of the selected challenge;
- Post the implementation of the challenge as a [question on the main-site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) tagged [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge);
- Post an answer to the [entry question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8442/code-review-2017-challenge-entries) posted [here on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/);
- Include a link to the entry question in the answer to the entry form;

You may update your entry at any time (which means you may post iterative reviews as well), all entries will be judged at the end of the challenge season (**Thursday, 30 November 2017**). Entries may make as many revisions as possible, but the question linked in the entry form at **23:59:59 UTC+0000** on **Thursday, 30 November 2017**.

---

Make sure you post the suggestions you have for this extravaganza in this question, the most upvoted answer at the end of the day on 31 August 2017 will become the challenge for this three-month extraordinaire!

Comment: So the idea is to award the cleanest implementation? It feels a bit counterintuitive, given the nature of this site. We are basically awarding the question, that does not need answers. Maybe we can come up with a system to award people who write good reviews to those questions as well? Similar to: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7102/best-of-code-review-2016

Comment: @NikitaB "So the idea is to award the cleanest implementation?" No, it's the person that scores the most points from the challenge. Anyway, why should we put bounty's on the winners answers? (assuming there is at least one.) This will function like 'Best Newcomer (question)' anyway.

Comment: @NikitaB We do want to promote clean code, don't we? Although the one with the most points might not necessarily be the cleaniest one, I would expect that it likely is the cleaniest one.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, I don't think I have to explain why you might want to award answers. It is completely obvious: code review is what this site is about, and it makes perfect sense to award best reviews. Also I did not propose to put "bounty's on the *winners* answers". Answers should be judged separately from questions, bad entries will probably have the best reviews. We could award people for catching a sneaky bug or making the best improvement to promote reviewing and challenge reviewers. But its ok if you disagree, I'm just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: @SimonForsberg, now that I think of it, it depends on the point system. If you get points by implementing additional features, then it is perfectly possible to get all the points with stylistically awful code.

Comment: @NikitaB Community challenges are like Hacker Rank and other challenge websites. For the same reason I don't think Hacker Rank should award Code Review.SE answers, I don't think Community challenges should either. I do however think, if _you_ think an answer is exemplary you can always put a bounty on it, using normal Code Review.SE guide lines.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, sure, I can do that. I can even make up the categories, that I would award. It is just weird to me, that this is not a part of official challenge. It looks like a perfect chance to draw more people into reviewing.

Comment: @NikitaB We already bounty answers during Winterbash. The idea of this challenge is to encourage the community to participate in a group-selected competition. We typically don't get much (if any) participations on community challenges as of late, this is sort of a last-ditch effort to change that. It *may* also help encourage users who never utilize Code Review to join to compete as well. Hell, it may even cause people to try out new languages/environments to learn something new. The basic idea is to encourage community participation.

Comment: I think some languages automatically generate more upvotes on questions than others..

Comment: Should there be a rule disallowing submissions that users started working on *before* the competition start date?

Comment: @EthanBierlein what actually counts as starting? I've had the beginnings of nafi (my language) in my head for years now, started banging out a bit of language specs this year, and even did a bit of exploratory coding towards an interpreter. I've since thrown out that code but the ideas remain. I'm writing a library right now I plan to use, does that count? Also, this is like the main reason I might get this to a workable state this year after sitting on it for multiple, I don't want to lose the opportunity for motivation. (tl;dr pls not too strict)

Comment: @EthanBierlein I think a requirement of was-not-functional-before-start-date is fair. (So PPCG users don't get to submit their preexisting golfing languages they built.) After that it's a case-by-case question on whether the work done beforehand is considered a library or exploratory enough that it's not a significant part. In any case, I'd use 1 June 2017 as the start.

Comment: Should this post be [featured]?

Comment: The link to the entry form should probably be updated with something that doesn't just link back to the main meta page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Write your own programming language

I think for this challenge we should make the barrier to entry low, the barrier to win high, but most of all it should be fun!

Since we're writing a language, it's always good to know that it works. And so to score each point that adds additional features requires a unit test. All unit test must be provided for you to score the point. To allow all languages to do this, you can verify the programs output in the language you're writing in. And so if you were to write your language in the Python programming language having a unit test such as the following would be valid:

```
import unittest

class TestStandardArithmetic(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_addition(self):
        # Replace `eval` with how you run your code
        self.assertEqual(eval('1 + 1'), 2)
```

### Requirements

- You won't be scored for any use of `eval` that's provided by your language. Posting `input()` as your language, and requiring Python 2 is a valid language, however *will score you no points*.
- When scoring each point, you must use your own implementation for that point to score the point. This allows you to use, say, the LLVM to implement tail recursion in your language by default, however when scoring the point for tail recursion, you have to use your own implementation of it rather than the one provided to you by the LLVM.
- Another person must be able to verify your language works. And so make it runnable from either Windows, Linux, Mac, or via a website.

  If it needs another program to run, such as CPython, the JVM, or a browser, that is fine. But it must be runnable on one of the above systems, or via a website.

  Since to do this we need to be able to get either a binary, or your code, entries need to produce a GitHub, or any other code sharing service, repository for their language. This allows entries to write Code Review questions on what they want reviewed, rather than a new question of their entire code on each change.
  This repository must be provided in the entry meta question on your entry.

### Scoring

Each bullet point is worth one point. 'Functions' may be prefix, infix or postfix operators, normal functions, or any other method that's usable in your language.

For each bullet point that adds an additional function or feature write a test case/suite with at least one unit test for each additional function or feature.

- Implement all standard operators/functions.

  - addition (`+`)
  - subtraction (`-`)
  - multiplication (`*`)
  - division (`/`)
  - less than (`<`)
  - less than or equal (`<=`)
  - greater than (`>`)
  - greater than or equal (`>=`)
  - equal (`==`)
  - not equal (`!=`)
  - binary or (`|`)
  - binary xor (`^`)
  - binary and (`&`)
  - binary invert (`~`)
  - binary left shift (`<<`)
  - binary right shift (`>>`)
  - boolean and (`&&`)
  - boolean or (`||`)
- Implement operator precedence. Perform, say, multiplication and division before addition and subtraction.
- Use [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) to generate a token stream.
- Use [syntactic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages) to generate an AST, or related structure.
- Have your language be directly interpreted.
- Have your language compile to an [intermediate language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation).
- Have your language compile to an [intermediate language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation) and then be executed by a 'virtual machine'. Your intermediate language must be custom-made in order to gain this point.
- Have your language compile directly to assembly.
- Write a Code Review question in your language.

In addition to the above you may also get points for implementing programming paradigms, according to [Scoring of paradigm support](https://github.com/CAD97/programming-paradigm-scoring). A big thanks to  [CAD97](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/100439/cad97) for making such a large list, anyone can add to.

---

I can't think of too many ways to score this, so if you can think of any, drop it as a comment, :)

Comment: I like this idea! Interestingly enough, I was thinking about proposing something similar earlier today, but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: @EthanBierlein Funnily enough, I was originally going to suggest doing a calculator, but [that's already been done before](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5176) ): If you have any ideas I've not posted, then I'd be more more then happy to hear them too, :)

Comment: A couple of ideas came to my head this morning while re-reading the post. Many of the bullet points seem to focus strongly around OOP and imperative programming, with little regard to other programming paradigms. Perhaps contestants could get a point for each paradigm their language allows?

Comment: @EthanBierlein Fair, I thought I included Functional too, maybe I should add tail recursion for that. I'll try learn a few key features of other paradigms to make bullet points for them. Thank you :) As for per paradigm, I don't really know how to score that, and for contestants to be able to 'prove' that.

Comment: In regards to proving paradigms, perhaps requiring contestants to submit paradigm-specific unit tests would work? In regards to scoring, +1 point for each paradigm implemented?

Comment: @EthanBierlein That could work, it may be a bit unfair on people that don't know the paradigms, but they're unlikely to implement a paradigm they don't know...

Comment: I'm already "working" on this for my own gratification, so +1 from me :P (Though I'd suggest avoiding giving points for allowing classes to inherit; e.g. [tag:rust] doesn't do that, and it'd be less fair if making a OO language got more point potential.)

Comment: @CAD97 My intent is for each paradigm to score points for being implemented, yes I've not included all paradigms, and I need to work on that. Another example of this is 'first-class and higher-order functions' are common in functional languages, but relatively uncommon in non-functional languages.

Comment: So, could I write an ANTLR file for a subset of C# and just run it with MS's C# tools? Wouldn't that fall under the "needing other programs to run"?

Comment: @Hosch250 I don't know enough about those things to be definitive. If I can download those tools on Windows, Linux or Mac, follow some instructions, and bam you language works, that is perfectly valid. However I first thought you were on about the `eval` point, do you think that passes the `eval` requirement? (I know near nothing of the three technology's you're on about)

Comment: No, it isn't eval, but it is kind of close. Basically, I would just have to write a  spec for a subset of an existing language, then run it as if it was a program written in that language.

Comment: @Hosch250 I think if you define a subset language and then run it through the compiler for the superset language that counts as an `eval`. Because you aren't interpreting the code yourself, you're using a different program to interpret the code. The spirit of the rule is that you can require programs as the platform for your language but you should do the actual transformation of source code into result yourself. However you could use an ANTLR file which did simple arithmetic for some points. Then your required platform software would be the ANTLR interpreter.

Comment: Just checking: the language I've been hacking on on-and-off (I'm working on supporting tooling currently for the next complete-rewrite-refactor stage) has and will have _a lot of supporting code_ as I'm making most of the toolchain from scratch (because the point is to learn about how programming languages work full-stack). How much of the project would be expected to be in the post and how much external? Could I break it into more manageable chunks?

Comment: @CAD97 Entries will be posted on meta, so a git link of the code is possible, if you don't want to post it all as code review questions. I'll update the answer tomorrow to include that. If you have any more questions, please just ask

Comment: One better: [Here's a list of some paradigms and suggestions for scoring.](https://github.com/CAD97/programming-paradigm-scoring) It's not perfect but it offers some structure and semblance of balance between features inherent to the different paradigms. It's not perfect, and it's definitely not a document for beginners, but just some of the knowledge I've picked up and my personal opinions on language features.

Comment: "Write a Code Review question in your language." I would be wary of this. Languages created for this challenge would be unlikely to be used elsewhere. Do we really want to open another question for it? It might be better to have some concrete thing to implement in your language, such as some sort of List type.

Comment: @Justin Just to share my plans: if I get NAFI (my pet language I'm starting work on) up and running in time, I plan to have at least one CR question on a standard library type. So something like an unbounded Integer built from the primitives in the language. And I plan to use NAFI as the (user-facing) script language for a game I have planned way in the future as well. Questions in the language would be judged as any other DSL question would be. If it's a good question, good. If it's bad, close it (and don't award the point).

Comment: @Justin [Here is the most recent meta discussion about Domain Specific Languages.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6609/100439) Consensus seems to be the questions are OK but unlikely to get much attention.

Comment: @CAD97 I understand that it would be on topic, but I still think it floods extra questions into the feed, which I personally don't think of as a good thing. On the one hand, if someone wanted to post a question using their language, I don't think there should be anything stopping them, but on the other hand, I don't think "requiring" (albeit a soft require) them to do so is a good idea.

Comment: @Justin First it's not a requirement, nor a soft requirement, it's purely optional. I also can't imagine anyone putting the effort into making a language and not wanting to write anything in it, so I see it as scoring the inevitable. Also, if this has as many entries as most other community challenges, there will be no extra questions, but for a flood of an extra question per day would require about 50 entries over the three month period. Which is not that much, but a lot more than I'd expect to enter.

Comment: There are many programming languages which implement an intermediary language or executable bytecode format of some kind (Python, C#, VB.NET, etc.) which code in the parent language is compiled to. If a contestant were to implement such a feature, how would it be scored?

Comment: @EthanBierlein Personally I don't know. We could say they're one language each, and possibly allow two languages, or just say one language per entrée, but IDK. How would you score them?

Comment: I'm leaning towards not scoring it at the moment, however if it is to be scored, then I'd say contestants get 1 point for implementing one.

Comment: Another, unrelated note: I have somewhat of an issue with the second-to-last scoring bullet point (Use an AST for your languages syntax.), as there are a not-insignificant number of languages which don't use ASTs, like concatenative or point-free languages.

Comment: @EthanBierlein I'm not sure how to fully phrase the intermarry language one, would you mind editing it in? As for your other comment, it's 'only' one point, making your code more functional / other paradigm would probably be easier and as rewarding... But I get you, there's a heavy bias to make your language a 'god language', which will likely have the drawbacks of a 'god class'.

Comment: Sure, I can see what I can edit in. As for the AST-related point, I guess I can agree.

Comment: @EthanBierlein Oh I forgot you can choose how to score it too, :) Yeah the AST / other features is a bit icky... I only really know like 2 languages, and so I'm out out of my domain here, so if you can think of a nice way to clean up the situation I'd be more than happy to look into it! :)

Comment: I've added some bullet points more related to language design into the scoring list. I removed the two points regarding base changing, since I felt that they were rather domain-specific.

Comment: @EthanBierlein Nice change, thank you, I like your additional bullet points. And I think it's fair that you removed the ones you did, they didn't really fit in.

Comment: No problem. If there's anything you think could be improved, feel free to change it or let me know. :)

Comment: Just a little thing: should binary operators on numbers be a "standard operation"? In a high level language, exposing bit-twiddling feels like an implementation leak, as it is directly consequent on the two's compliment representation of integers. If you want to give points for bit-twiddling operations, score them separately from the arithmetic. (I have yet to encounter a problem where bit-twiddling was the _best_ and _clearest_ way of solving a problem, instead of an optimization.)

Comment: Clarification: the two times you mention intermediate language is the difference between <transpile to C++ which is then compiled> and <compile to instructions for a custom VM>?

Comment: @CAD97 Using the [TIOBE Index for June 2017](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/) of all the top 20 languages only Delphi, R, MATLAB and Scratch didn't have bitwise operators. No Bitwise operators are not bad abstraction. Yes they have their uses, take the [C# FlagsAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Also if you need to do low level stuff, even in a high level language, bitwise operators help simplify things.

Comment: As for your second comment CAD97, I think it's best to ask @EthanBierlein. But I think the answer would be transpiling would not score the point as C++ is a language, not an intermediate language like Java bytecode.

Comment: For "Implement Operator Precendence", what about languages where there is no precedence? For example, Clojure has none (IIRC); it's all "prefix", because everything is a function: `x * y + z` would be written as `(+ z (* x y))`

Comment: For scoring, there's a few things to consider. For example, what if someone used LLVM? "Implement the tail call optimization for recursive functions" would be free then.

Comment: @Justin I'm in favour for not giving the point. Whilst it is likely to promote bad code, if you don't implement it then I don't think you should be rewarded the point. Just for the same reason I wouldn't give someone that wrote `input` as their program in Python 2 any points.

Comment: @Peilonrayz You're talking about LLVM, right? I'm actually in favor if giving the point. I guess you could require that the implementation actually implements the tail recursion but doesn't necessarily need to use that (reinvent the wheel, but use the already designed wheel).

Comment: Do eDSL languages count? For example, if I embed a `Toy` language in Haskell, does this still count as my "own" language?

Comment: @Zeta My requirements for a language is does it take a string / file as input, and output what the language spec says it should. To score points however you have to, within reason, implement it yourself. So `eval(input())` in Python / JavaScript will score you no points.

Answer (score 12):

Reposting Simon's [answer from April:](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7208/31562)

### Chess!

Last year ended with a board-game spree. Let's continue this year with one.

I think you all know the game of [Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess), which is exactly why I just linked to the Wikipedia page. Even though everyone knows it, you might not know all the details about it.

What I like about a Chess challenge is that it can be both a small and a large challenge, depending on what you want to do with it. Let's take a look at some possible challenges for Chess: (feel free to pick the ones you want)

1. Implement logic to determine where/how pieces can move/attack
2. Determine which squares are threatened by what pieces
3. Implement support for some [Chess notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_notation) (there are a bunch to choose from)
4. Given a history of chess moves, check if all moves are valid and figure out how the board looks like now.
5. Interact with the [Lichess API](https://github.com/ornicar/lila#http-api) for example [use this data and implement the above](https://en.lichess.org/api/game/5bhAdgLq?with_moves=1)
6. Make a GUI
7. Make a Chess computer opponent
8. Make a Chess computer opponent that beats [Stockfish level 8](https://stockfishchess.org/) (good luck with that)
9. Implement some [Chess variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_variants) such as [Atomic Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_chess)
10. Probably a bunch of other stuff

### Scoring:

Item 1 is required. If you don't have that, it doesn't count as a submission. Items 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 are worth one point for each variant supported, with another point for each variant implemented (item 9). Item 7 is significantly more difficult, so it gets 2 points for the engine and one point for the scoring system for each variant supported. If you implement item 8, you win outright and get a 500 point bounty from me (SE's limit).

Item 10 is rather vague, so I will give you one point per item implemented, but it has to be a serious feature of at least the complexity of item 1--in other words, don't try to bolster your ratings; if the community feels a player is attempting to do this, it is their responsibility to jointly decide a more fair rating. Additionally, if a player feels one point is too low for a feature's complexity, they can petition the community to grant them a higher score.

Answer (score 4):

## Create an image from any given file.

The objective is to create an image from any file, per instance, text file, audio file, or any other file. This is more of a challenge where people should be creative.

Just imagine see text as an image, or even an assembly! We programmers would finally be able to see code as an image (for the first time in history?).

## Scoring:

1. Your program works on any text file (UTF-8) (1 point)
2. Your program works on any file type (1 point)
3. Your program does not require external libraries (1 point)
4. You are able to generate jpeg files (1 point)
5. You are able to generate png files (1 point)
6. You are able to generate bmp files (1 point)
7. You are able to generate gif files (2 points)
8. The generated image is different if the file type is different (1 point)
9. Relative beauty of generated images (this is a subjective qualification, post your results on your question!)

Total possible score: 9 + beauty

Comment: Could you expand a little on "Your algorithm does not require external libraries". If I make image be a 2D array of pixels, and just mutate that in my language of choice is, then move that to my external data type. Is that allowed? Also, does it mean I can't use use an external library to make all of jpeg, png, bmp, gif?

Comment: @Peilonrayz You can use them, but you get an additional point if you don't use them. This is only libraries not included with your run-time environment. What this means is that your are allowed to use any libraries offered by your run-time, but not libraries by a git-hub project, nugget, npm, etc

Comment: Could you change "Your algorithm" to "Your program" on point 3 then please :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz I thought I would make it a bit less penalizing there's no reason giving it 2 points.

Comment: I'd personally make it like 5 / double points. Without it I can do the rest of your program in like an hour with Python and PIL...

Comment: @Peilonrayz No worries on that. The challenge is not to create your own image processing libraries. Would like to see your entry on this

Comment: What kind of image do you expect from an audio file?

Comment: @SimonForsberg It's about being creative. You choose how you [transform audio into an image](http://convert.ing-now.com/generate-a-waveform-image-from-an-audio-file/) or [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&q=nature&gws_rd=cr&ei=rhBAWaPeGYataebSv-gL)

Answer (score 3):

## Allocate resources efficiently on a work environment

The company Code42Review demands that their **employees** are able to handle **work items** as efficiently as possible.

Those **work items** are assigned according to the **work item chooser** that decides which work items get assigned to which employees.
The work item chooser takes into account the **skills** needed by a certain work item and tries to match them as close as possible to the skills of an employee.
While some skills are mandatory others are "nice to have".
The work item chooser may delay assignment due to not having any employee available with a required skill.

A **work item** only exists if a **work candidate** has **acquired all resources** sucessfully.
Acquiring a resource is a process that may require time, in this particular work envoirnment, up to 20 seconds.
The process of acquiring a resource is not guarteed to succeed because such resources might not be available. (the successful rate of resource acquisition is tipically under 50%)

In this work enviorment an employee may take up to several minutes to complete a work item. Usually something between 2 and 20 minutes.
An employee that is handling a work item is considered to be busy and may not have another work item assigned to him.

A work item should be assigned to an employee within the shortest amount of time possible, if it's not assigned to an employee within a reasonable time,
the resources may no longer be available. In this scenario the work item will be replaced by another.

## Scoring

Your job is to create a program that does the following

1. Employees should spend the least amount of time possible waiting for work items (up to 10 points, scored according to the average amount of waiting time, 10 being awarded to the smallest)
2. Work items are discarded as few times as possible (up to 10 points, scored according to the amount of discarded work items, 10 being awarded to the smallest)
3. Work items are assigned to an employee within the shortest amount of time possible (up to 10 points, scored according to the average amount of assignment time, 10 being awarded to the smallest)
4. Work items are assigned to employees according to their skillet while respecting all the above (7 points, optional)
5. Do your own work environment simulator, according to the rules I stated. (if there is anything that is missing please edit, or comment, assume normal distribution) (7 points, optional)

Total score - 44 points.

Comment: The values given are an example and the solution should work for any other given values.